# VB NET - Select * From issue

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have some wierd exception.
I have Access database with 2 tables, one named `MYSB_DB` and the other `Employee`.

I'm using the code below when I want to filter on something like that:

```vb
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql As String = String.Empty ' 
Dim pName As String = String.Empty
Dim fName As String = String.Empty
Dim ColpName As String = String.Empty
Dim ColfName As String = String.Empty
Dim ch As Integer = InStr(1, cmbEmployees.Text, " ", CompareMethod.Text)

pName = cmbEmployees.Text.Substring(0, ch)
fName = cmbEmployees.Text.Substring(ch, cmbEmployees.Text.Length - ch)
ColpName = "שדה1"
ColfName = "שדה2"
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE [" & ColpName & "]=" & pName & ";"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString)
da.Fill(ds, Me.MYSB_DataBaseDataSet1.Employee.TableName)
```

I only change between the tables name in the code.
When I'm using this code for `MYSB_DB` table, the code is running well, but when I'm using the code for `Employee` table, I have an exception.

Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: well what is the exception and what debugging says,which line?

Comment: Please [do not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/11683) do [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683). This will also solve your problem.

Comment: Hey Neel. the exception occured on da.Fill(ds, Me.MYSB_DataBaseDataSet1.Employee.TableName). and the the exception is (I have VS hebrew version, so I'll try to translate: "No value given for one or more parameters"  THanks!

Comment: Hey Gserg and thank you!  for now I chnaged the sql command to " sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE " & ColpName & " = '" & pName & "';" and it works fine.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

`pName` is a string, so it must be quoted:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE [" & ColpName & "]='" & pName & "';"
```

Comment: Hey Gustav.  in the end I did so and it worked. thanks!

Comment: While this solves the immediate problem, I'm tempted to downvote for promoting [bad things](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683).

Comment: @GSerg: I know. However, here `pName` is derived from a combobox we may assume the questioneer is in control of.